# Concatenation of Records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I need to fetch the data from SQL Server based on the below condition.

In the database there are columns `Ticketnumber` and `comments`. For a `Ticketnumber` there are multiple records, for the same ticket number there are multiple comments stored in different records. Whenever I retrieve the `ticketnumber` and `comments` columns, the comments should be concatenated in the single record.

Let's look at an example:

```
Ticketnumber       Comments        
-------------------------------
1002               Case raised    
1003               Case raised
1002               Processing,
1003               resolved
1002               resolved
```

Expected output should be:

```
Ticketnumber       Comments
-----------------------------------------------
1002               Case raise,processing,resolved,
1003               case raised,resolved
```

All the comments should be concatenated for single `ticketnumber` as above.

Please provide the query. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select X.Ticketnumber,
       Left(X.yourtable,Len(X.yourtable)-1) As "comments"
From
    (
        Select distinct y.Ticketnumber, 
            (
                Select x.comments  + ',' AS [text()]
                From dbo.yourtable x
                Where x.Ticketnumber= y.Ticketnumber
                ORDER BY x.SubjectID
                For XML PATH ('')
            ) [yourtable]
        From dbo.yourtable y
    ) [X]
```

Taken help from the [source thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: Thanks Rahul,  for your quick response, If i need to pull multiple columns apart from this then where should i add column names.

Comment: @shaikahamad:- `If you want to pull multiple columns`..I didnt get that!

Comment: Above we are fetching two columns only right, if any need to fetch other columns too, then how?  ex: Ticketnumber , comments, id , user, time these are the columns i need to fetch, but Comments only  i need to concatenate  .

Comment: @shaikahamad:- You just have to add it at the first select like this: `Select X.Ticketnumber,
       Left(X.yourtable,Len(X.yourtable)-1) As 'comments',id,user,time....`

Comment: @shaikahamad:- Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you , Let me try this. i believe it would work

Comment: @shaikahamad:- Do accept the answer if that helps. (The right tick mark turning green when clicked)

Comment: I got this error : [SQL Server]The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Hi ,  i have tried this code it is giving little diff results, means comments are not coming in order, it is coming in the order of comment 3 ,comment 1 and comment 2

Answer (score 0):

There was a previous post w/ an answer for something similar here:

[Concatenate many rows into a single text string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string)

Comment: you should post the answer here as well (along with the link with the source), since the link may become unavailable.

Comment: It's a stackoverflow link.  If anything, he should flag the question as a duplicate.